# Why is my product cost average coming out at 0?

Tags: c

```
//Program Written By: Andre Chitsaz-zadeh
//Program Written On: 10/7/12
//Program calculates book cost for multiple book orders. 
//Program written using multiple functions.

#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

void inputData();
void processingData(float costs[]);
float costs[5];
float sortedCosts[5];

int main()
{
   inputData();
   processingData(costs);
}

void inputData()
{
   int i = 0;
   printf("\nPlease enter five products costs.\n");
   while (i < 5)
   {
      scanf("%d", &costs[i]);
      i = i + 1;
   }
}

void processingData(float costs[])
{
   int i;
   int j;
   float sum = 0.00f;
   float average = 0.00f;
   for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
   {
      int j, min, temp;
      min = i;
      for (j = i + 1; j < 5; ++j)
         if (costs[j] < costs[min])
            min = j;
      temp = costs[i];
      costs[i] = costs[min];
      costs[min] = temp;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
         sortedCosts[i] = costs[i];

   for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      sum += costs[i];
   average = sum / 5;
   printf("Product Cost Average = %.2f\n", average);
}
```

Why is my product cost average coming out as zero? As far as I can see all of my variables are declared as float? I have tried all sorts of combinations and I cant seem to get it to work. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It would be useful to know what you need to achieve with the code. There are several errors btw..

Comment: Over and over, UB using scanf... Hey guys, Y U NO read some C standard before asking/doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &costs[i]);
```

`cost[i]` is of type `float` in your program not `int`.

Use `%f` conversion specification to read a `float`.

Also:

```
temp = costs[i];
```

Your `temp` value is of type `int` but `costs[i]` is of type `float`. I don't think it is deliberate.

Comment: Thanks, I was also wondering why my average was slightly off but the mistake you caught with my temp variable fixed it! You were quick too, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Use the "%f" modifier in *scanf* to get a float, rather than "%d".

Also, you

```
#define SIZE 5
```

but you use 5's throughout your code rather than SIZE.  Use SIZE to reduce the possibility of bugs.

There's nothing *wrong* with

```
i = i + 1;
```

but that is much more commonly written as

```
i++;
```